# Find MAX of a summed value on multiple group by clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title indicates, I am trying to find the maximum summed value in column C for an object in column A based on a subset of column B over a period of time (let's say column D). My current query looks something like this in which I return the summed values greater than 10,000.

```
select id_a, id_b, sum(column_c) from master_table where id_b in (1,2,3,4,5) 
and ymdh >= '2017-11-01' group by 1,2 having sum(column_c) > 10000 order by 2,3
desc;
```

What I'm trying to get returned is the greatest value from sum(column_c). I tried using both the max() and distinct() functions. Specifically using max(sum(imps)), but aggregate function calls many not be nested. Would anyone be able to provide guidance here?

Comment: Do you have any sample data, in the database design you are using, with the expected output?

Comment: Have you tried a subquery for selecting the max result from that previous query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a FROM  (   select  ) T

```
select max(my_sum) 
from (
    select id_a
      , id_b
      , sum(column_c)  my_sum
    from master_table 
    where id_b in (1,2,3,4,5) 
      and ymdh >= '2017-11-01' 
    group by 1,2 having my_sum > 10000 
    order by 2,3 desc;
) T
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly :)

Comment: `having sum(column_c)` can become `having my_sum` - No need to run SUM again.

Comment: @MrMarlow   yes correct  .. thanks  answer  updated  with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select id_a, id_b, sum(column_c)
from master_table
where id_b in (1,2,3,4,5) and
      ymdh >= '2017-11-01'
group by id_a, id_b
having sum(column_c) > 10000 
order by sum(column_c) desc
limit 1;
```

That is, use `order by` and `limit` to get the value you want.  (This query includes the `group by` keys as well, but that is not necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

scaisEdge has the answer (and my +1) - but I just wanted to add a bit about the thought process when designing an SQL statement like you're working on.

Don't feel you need to compose the whole thing - that it's one big statement, or that it's one single query.

Instead, you'll often need to break up the problem into steps, solve the individual steps, and then use those steps as sources for a query - because you don't have to use tables in the FROM clause; you can use your own subqueries instead.

So for this problem?  You've got the first step done - you figured out how to write the query that gets the Sum over a particular grouping:

```
select someCol, sum(otherCol) as groupSum from myTable
group by someCol
```

Great!  Now, you can effectively use this like it's a table:

```
select someCol, groupSum
from
(
    select someCol, sum(otherCol) as groupSum from myTable
    group by someCol
) mySubquery
```

And in your case, you want to get the maximum sum?

```
select max(groupSum)
from
(
    select someCol, sum(otherCol) as groupSum from myTable
    group by someCol
) mySubquery
```

Not only will this help while composing the full SQL statement, it'll actually help the person trying to read/debug it down the line, especially if you name your subqueries/columns well:

```
select max(totalHitsForWeek) as maxWeeklyUsage
from
(
    select week, sum(hits) as totalHitsForWeek
    from requestsTable
) hitsPerWeekSubquery
```

Hope that helps add to scaisEdge's answer!  :-)